# SonarLint says I should remove or rename the parameter being used

Tags: typescript, sonarlint

Sonar lint says:

> Remove the unused function parameter "customParams" or rename it to "_customParams" to make intention explicit.

But, the "customParams" parameter is being used in the "getNextUrl" method, what are I doing wrong?

```js
class Pagination {
  private readonly maxPage: number

  constructor (
    private readonly data: Array<{}>,
    private readonly currentPage: number,
    private readonly limit: number,
    private readonly count: number,
    private readonly urlRoute: string,
    private readonly customParams: {} = {}
  ) {
    this.maxPage = Math.ceil(count / limit)
  }

  private getNextUrl (): string | null {
    if (this.currentPage >= this.maxPage) {
      return null
    }
    const query = toQueryString({
      page: this.currentPage + 1,
      limit: this.limit,
      ...this.customParams
    })
    return getUrl(this.urlRoute) + '?' + query
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it means that you define it in the constructor but never pass something to that Pagination() constructor for `customParams` so you allow for customParams to be sent in like:

```js
const paginator = new Pagination(
    [{}], //    private readonly data: Array<{}>,
    0, // private readonly currentPage: number,
    100, // private readonly limit: number,
    87, // private readonly count: number,
    '/pages', // private readonly urlRoute: string,
    { someCustom: 3000 }, // private readonly customParams: {} = {}
  );
```

It is possible to fill out customParams but nowhere in your code did you actually provide any so... customParams is only ever defined as `{}` which is how you initiated it. If there's nobody using customParams yet, why bother defining it? (YAGNI = you aren't going to need it).

Perhaps actually use `customParams` or set it at the top of the file like you did with `maxPage` or don't include it at all.

If you were to run `cmd` + `shift` + `f` (in Mac VS-Code/Sublime/Atom/etc your code editor) you can search for all usages of the `Pagination` class. It seems that there is no use case currently (neither dynamic nor hardcoded that actually defines `customParams` aka the 6th argument passed in the constructor.

Also, while we're discussing code-styling some linters will fault you for not using the concept of `named params` a single object  parameter which accepts all the potentially optional params (where you might have a long list of 4+ params) because that strategy it is easier to remember the order of the params. It will be hard for the user of the software to remember that they can pass a 6th param for `customParams` (especially if it is optional). So just as a potential improvement try defining functions with many params (usually more than 3) with just 1 param that is an object and can take optional params.

```js
interface PaginationOptions {
 data: Array<{}>,
 currentPage: number,
 limit: number,
 count: number,
 urlRoute: string,
 customParams?: Record<string, any>
}

constructor({ data, currentPage, limit, count, urlRoute, customParams = {} }: PaginationOptions)
```